# Close pop up in edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am running a legacy app in MS edge in IE mode. Pages on web app can open a pop up in new window (but this on edge and not IE mode) using window.open.

When pop up is launched, this pop up redirects to another url on same pop up window.

now window.close is throwing some error and not closing the pop up. Is it due to Ms edge IE mode to Edge pop issue?

I have not catched the exception but the exception is coming.

Comment: What error does it show when using `window.close`? Could you please [provide a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? So that we can have a test and try to help.

Comment: documentWindow = window.open(parameters) is used to open pop up. This documentWindow is coming null lthough pop up is launched.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you loading the parent window in IE mode and the pop up window in Edge mode? If so, I can reproduce the issue. `documentWindow` is null in parent window. I think it might be related with Edge/IE mode changing after all they're different kernel browsers.

Comment: Yes Zhou, you are right but what is the solution. As the parent window which is of legacy application is not compatible with edge and pop is not compatible with IE mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to get the Edge window handler in IE browser, so it's impossible to get `documentWindow` to close the window.

As you can't use the two windows in the same browser kernel, the only workaround I think is using `window.self.close()` to close the pop up window by itself.